# How do I code the function of the Save button in Java?

Tags: java, file, button, text, save

I have an existing text file and edited some stuff in it. I want to save a line of text to that same file. Currently, my Save button will create a new file for the text file I just edited. What I want is that my Save button will just overwrite the existing file. What code do I need to write on it?

Here's my current code:

```
private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

    int choice = fc.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (choice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        String filename = fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        writeToFile(filename);
    }
}
```

here's my writeToFile code:

```
       private void writeToFile(String filename) {
       Person p = getPersonFromDisplay();
       PersonFileMgr.save(filename, p);
   }
```

Comment: What code do you have right now?

Comment: Where is writeToFile method?

Comment: Sorry it took too long.

Answer (score 1):

To overwrite a file without creating a whole new file. Use `FileWriter` and `BufferedWriter`

**example:**

Inside your `writeToFile` method

```
try{
    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("out.txt",true);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    out.write("Hi\n");
    out.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
InputStream ios = null;
OutputStream out = null;
try {
    ios = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[SIZE];
    int read;
    out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    while ((read = ios.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        out.flush();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.error("Saving failed", e);
} finally {
    if (ios != null) {
        ios.close();
    }
    if (out != null) {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Make the notice that in our current code you don't need several variables as choice and filename and you could inline them. There is no reason to have them.